# Accessing one of the multiple instances of a bean

Tags: java, spring

I need to define multiple instances of a bean and I want to access one of the beans from my Manager in Spring.

Bean Definitions:

```
<bean class="org.oba.GtfsRealtimeSource">
  <property name="name" value="PSTA" />
 </bean>

 <bean class="org.oba.GtfsRealtimeSource">
  <property name="name" value="HART" />
 </bean>
```

Is there any way to access all of the Beans from the `ApplicationContext` or with `annotations`? I try to access in following way, but I always get the first defined `bean`.

```
GtfsRealtimeSource grc = (GtfsRealtimeSource)
    applicationContext.getBean("org.oba.GtfsRealtimeSource");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method getBeansOfType(), for your case:

```
Map<String, GtfsRealtimeSource> grcMap = 
    applicationContext.getBeansOfType(GtfsRealtimeSource.class);
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Is there any way to get with annotations?

Comment: Yes, of course you can use it with "@Autowired": @Autowired
  private Map<String,GtfsRealtimeSource> grcMap;